# How is the ID Converted to A Task?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to understand this Symfony code:

https://github.com/lyrixx/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Controller/TaskController.php

In particular:

```
/**
 * @Route("/show/{id}", name="task_show")
 */
public function showAction(Task $task)
{
    return $this->render('task/show.html.twig', [
        'task' => $task,
    ]);
}
```

How does Symfony need to know that the {id} in the Route should get converted to the $task in **showAction(Task $task)**?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony uses [parameter converters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) under the hood. Their use is *optional* with the `@ParamConverter` annotation, but *implicit* when the method is type-hinted as in your example. One could rewrite your example using an explicit call as:

```
/**
 * @Route("/show/{id}", name="task_show")
 * @ParamConverter("task", "AppBundle\Entity\Task:Task")
 */
public function showAction($task)
```

This functionality is based around the objects being Doctrine models, as documented in the [controllers section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter) of the Symfony manual:

> Normally, you'd expect a $id argument to showAction(). Instead, by creating a new argument ($post) and type-hinting it with the Post class (which is a Doctrine entity), the ParamConverter automatically queries for an object whose $id property matches the {id} value. It will also show a 404 page if no Post can be found.